# Pulling parent data from Trigger context variable

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written below code in my Opportunity after update trigger

```
Map<Id,Opportunity> newOpptyMap = Trigger.newMap;
Map<Id,Opportunity> oldOpptyMap = Trigger.oldMap;
Map<Id,Opportunity> removeShareMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();

for(Opportunity newOppty:newOpptyMap.values()){
        Opportunity oldOppty = oldOpptyMap.get(newOppty.Id);
        if(oldOppty.Account.fieldA__c == false && newOppty.fieldA__c == true){
            removeShareMap.put(newOppty.Id,newOppty);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting following error  **Error: Compile Error: Invalid field fieldA_*c for SObject Opportunity fieldA*_c  is a custom field in Account object in my org**.What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: If `fieldA__c` is on Account, it's never going to show a difference. If you're looking for something changing during Opportunity update, it will have to be an Opportunity field that changes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(oldOppty.Account.fieldA__c == false && newOppty.Account.fieldA__c == true){
        removeShareMap.put(newOppty.Id,newOppty);
}
```

You are not traversing in the trigger.new record through Account as above.

The above code also assumes that you have to query the fields on the **Account** using a SOQL before traversing.

Also note you will need to make sure to query for the Related fields on Account when working on the **Opportunity** object.

Comment: In this example, `fieldA__c` is not available from the triggering record, since it is on a related object. You would need to query for that Account. But value of the field is going to be the same before and after, since the Account isn't being updated here, the Opportunity is.

Comment: @Jeremy Nottingham, that means I can't pull related object data from Trigger context variables and need to query them explicitly ?

Comment: That's correct; related objects are not automatically available in triggers. It also means that if you're looking for a field change on the Account object, you need to use an Account Trigger.